# calclulate a sum excluding NA results. SP10

Tags: calculated-column

I have 6 columns.

Each column has a `NA`, `1` or `0` entered.

I need `column7` to calculate a score (preferably as a percentage), however NA should not be included in the count.

EG

```
1,  1,  1,  0,  NA, 1  =  4/5

0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1 = 3/6

NA,  NA,  1, 1, 1, 1 = 4/4
```

Comment: If Atish answered your question, then please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say, six columns are `C1`, `C2`, `C3`, `C4`, `C5`, `C6`. So now you can just check the value before adding and dividing. I mean following

```
=(
   IF(C1="NA",0,C1) +
   IF(C2="NA",0,C2) +
   IF(C3="NA",0,C3) +
   IF(C4="NA",0,C4) +
   IF(C5="NA",0,C5) +
   IF(C6="NA",0,C6) 
 )/
 ( 
  IF(C1="NA",0,1) + 
  IF(C2="NA",0,1) +
  IF(C3="NA",0,1) +
  IF(C4="NA",0,1) +
  IF(C5="NA",0,1) +
  IF(C6="NA",0,1) 
 )
```

## Explanation

1. `IF(C1="NA",0,C1)` means It will add `0` if `C1` is `NA`. Otherwise
   it will add `C1` itself. So `NA` is no more in the sum.
2. `IF(C6="NA",0,1)` mean the count will not increase if the value is
   `NA`

## Output using question's Input

[image]

If you need (A/B) type output, then you can use following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(
 (
   IF(C1="NA",0,C1) +
   IF(C2="NA",0,C2) +
   IF(C3="NA",0,C3) +
   IF(C4="NA",0,C4) +
   IF(C5="NA",0,C5) +
   IF(C6="NA",0,C6) 
 ),
 "/",
 (
  IF(C1="NA",0,1) + 
  IF(C2="NA",0,1) +
  IF(C3="NA",0,1) +
  IF(C4="NA",0,1) +
  IF(C5="NA",0,1) +
  IF(C6="NA",0,1) 
 )
)
```

In that case output will be like following

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. however I don't believe this worked in a calculated column in SP.

Comment: Did you try?....

Comment: There was a extra plus sign (+). I have updated my answer

Comment: Hello, This formula did not work in my calculated column. I have received this error:The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported. Maybe I need to create a Nintex workflow instead of a calculated column..

Comment: Did you change the column names properly?

Comment: I did change the column titles in the formula to reflect the column titles on my list

Comment: Ohhh no!!! Change the column names... Meaning C1, C2....C6 by your own